# Is WebAPI hosted outside of application pool process?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm trying to figure out why system process (PID 4) is handling WebAPI traffic instead of application pool process which I would expect when WebAPI is hosted within IIS.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the http.sys who handles the TCP/IP part and then forward the packets to worker processes. This, if you use tools like this, you see the process 4 (system) performs the activities. That's by design.

Comment: That does not seem to be right since classic ASP.NET showing connections being handled by w3wp.exe worker process not by system process. I'm pretty sure you will be able to see for yourself if you have any instance of IIS running.

Comment: If a worker process handles the TCP connections that means some web applications connect to other services or it deliberately opens a port. That fact won't invalidate the facts I described above as that's how IIS was designed for releases since IIS 6.